# Using guards after assigning some variables first

Tags: haskell, syntax

I know I can do this...

```
isZero :: Int -> Bool
isZero x
  | x == 0      = True
  | otherwise   = False
```

But can I do something like this?

```
isPalindrome :: Int -> Bool
isPalindrome x
  let digitList = intToDigits x -- Decomposes the integer into
                                -- digits, i.e. 37 -> [3, 7]
  | digitList == reverse digitList                = True
  | otherwise                                     = False
```

This will result in compilation errors, but I'm sure that you know what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Using a language's conditional expressions ("if/then/else", case statements, or guards) to return a `Bool` usually means there is an equivalent single expression that evaluates to the correct `Bool`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use a `where` clause instead

```
isPalindrome :: Int -> Bool
isPalindrome x
    | digitList == reverse digitList = True
    | otherwise                      = False
    where digitList = intToDigits x
```

Of course, for this example we could just skip the guards and write

```
isPalindrome x = digitList == reverse digitList
    where digitList = intToDigits x
```

Comment: Bonus: since Haskell is lazy, statements in the where clause are not evaluated until they are required by one of the guards. For example (not related to your particular problem), the first guard could can catch the empty list condition, and the later guards can rely on where-clause expressions that would error on an empty list.

Answer (score 3):

Why not do

```
isPalindrome x = digitList == reverse digitList
  where digitList = intToDigits x
```